# Cant access global variable with value in it

Tags: java, android

I use a GlobalClass to handle my global variables.
Now I want to set the value directly in the GlobalClass.

like:
GlobalClass:

```
public static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
```

and in another Activity I need the variable like:

```
if (jsonStr.toString().getString(GlobalClass.KEY_SUCCESS) != null)
```

and I get this error:

```
The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String
```

of course, when I dont use global variable it works.

why?

Comment: Please post the working code as well, the error you're getting is not related to GlobalClass.KEY_SUCCESS.

Comment: The method getString seems to be the problem. Not the global variable (try to avoid them because generally they are code smells). Jsonstr's toString() returns a String, how can you ask it for a String to be returned?

Comment: the variable jsonStr is a String, the getString-method is used for JSONObjects. i changed the jsonStr to be a JSONObject. That solved it by myself i think ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toString() returns a String object. On this object you are trying to invoke a method called getString. The String class has no such method.

This is in no way related to your GlobalClass.

If you post enough code it might be possible to elaborate on what you should do instead, but assuming jsonStr is a JSONObject, it would make sense to call getString on it directly, NOT first toString and then getString.

Comment: the variable jsonStr is a String, the getString-method is used for JSONObjects. i changed the jsonStr to be a JSONObject. That solved it by myself i think ^^.